# Creating an animation that counts up to the browser's viewport dimensions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I currently have a small scrip that returns the height and width of my browser window. What I'm having trouble with is implementing a way for the height and width to count up from zero to the current dimensions on load. It would function similar to this: http://jsfiddle.net/YWn9t/ but the target number(s) would be the dimensions mentioned above. Can this be done using even less code than there is the jsfiddle?

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {text-align: center;}

div {border: 2px solid #000; display: inline-block; padding: 5px 20px; vertical-align: middle;}

span:first-of-type:after {content: "|"; margin: 0 10px;}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    showViewportSize();
});

$(window).resize(function (e) {
    showViewportSize();
});

function showViewportSize() {
    var the_width = $(window).width();
    var the_height = $(window).height();
    $('span:first-of-type').text(the_width);
    $('span:last-of-type').text(the_height);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AM9kL/).

JS

```
$('#start').on('click', function(){

  var windowheight = $(window).height();
  var windowwidth  = $(window).width();
  $('.putmehere1').html('height: ' + 
                         windowheight + 
                         'width: ' + 
                        windowwidth);

  var startwidth = 0;
  var endwidth = windowwidth;
  var startheight = 0;
  var endheight = windowheight;
  var timer;
  var timer2;

timedCount();
timedCount2();


function timedCount()
{
   startwidth = startwidth + 1;
   timer = setTimeout(function(){timedCount()}, 20);
   $('.putwidth').html(startwidth);
   if (startwidth == endwidth)
      {
       clearTimeout(timer);
       startwidth = endwidth;
       }
}

function timedCount2()
{
   startheight = startheight + 1;
   timer2 = setTimeout(function(){timedCount2()}, 20);
   $('.putheight').html(startheight);
   if (startheight == endheight)
   {
       clearTimeout(timer2);
       startheight = endheight;
    }
}

 });
```

Comment: I don't understand how would this would be implemented into what I have now.

Comment: Then it's clear I don't understand your question. Your fiddle is a counter up to 2,500. There is lots of code. Your code does nothing to slowly open a window. Your last sentence, and I assume your question, is "Can this be done using even less code than there is the jsfiddle?". - I've given you a counter with less code, and you can take the number out of the counter (startseconds) and use it to slowly scroll up a page, or use it to reveal the contexts of a page container. What did I miss in your question?

Comment: Here is a quick fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/5fVyt/ - that slowly reveals the contents of the page based on the timer. Is this what you're trying to do? Read the current dimensions, and put them in the endseconds variable.

Comment: This should give you a better idea: http://howbigismybrowser.com. Note the two numeric values in the div. They both represent the height and width of the browser window. The aim is to alter the current script to count up from 0 to that particular resolution in an allotted time.

Comment: Third time's a charm. How about this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/AM9kL/. It reads the window height and width with jQuery, then passes those two variables to counters that count up from zero.

Comment: Yes! Is there a way start this onload & how could I set the duration of the counter so that for example I set the entire animation to finish in 1.5 seconds?

Comment: To start onload just put it in a script at the bottom in a $(document).ready(function(){});. The timing is going to be trial and error. It is not like an .animate where you set the total time of animation. You'll have to adjust the last number in the timer = line. It won't be 1.5 seconds, but you'll be able to get it close.

Comment: Cheers my friend. If it its not too much to ask, would you mind editing your post and putting in the full solution with adjustments mentioned above so that I can approve this?